# zf2 Form class issue

Tags: zend-framework2

ABOVE URLS IS NOT ANSWERS, I AM ALREADY PASSING DB ADAPTOR

I am having issue in calling "Db\RecordExists" in Filter form class.

I AM ALREADY PASSNING DB ADAPTPR IN CONTROLLER.

```
$sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
 $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');

 $form->setInputFilter(new RegisterStepFirstFilter($dbAdapter));    
                    $form->setData($request->getPost()); 
                    if (!$form->isValid()) {    

}
```

I want to check email exist or not during registration.  I am using Zend framework form class for Registration. I have define the form class and Class Filter and calling them in Controller.

Every things is working fine except "Db\RecordExists". The form is not checking unique email against db ad it simply submitter. However the other filters and validators are working properly

```
$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'user_email',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                array('name' => 'HtmlEntities'),

            ),
            'validators' => array(
                            array('name' => 'EmailAddress'),
                            array('name' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 200,),
                            array('name' => 'Db\RecordExists', 'options' => array('table' => 'y2m_user','field' => 'user_email',  'adapter' => $dbAdapter),),
                ),
            ),
        ));
```

my form class is

```
<?php
namespace User\Form;
use Zend\Form\Form; 

class RegisterStepFirst extends Form
{ 
     protected $captchaElement= null;

    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        // we want to ignore the name passed
        parent::__construct('user');
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

        //$this->add(array('hash','csrf_token',array('salt'=>get_class($this).'s3cr3t%Ek@on9!'));   

        $this->add(array(
     'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Csrf',
     'name' => 'csrf',
     'options' => array(
             'csrf_options' => array(
                     'timeout' => 600,
                     'salt' => 'unique'
             )
     )
 ));

       $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'user_given_name',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Display Name',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'user_given_name',                              
            ) 
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'user_email',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Email',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'mail@yourdomain', //set selecarray()ted to '1'
                'id' => 'user_email',
                'size'  => '100',

            ) 
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'user_password',
            'type' => 'Password',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Password',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(               
                'id' => 'user_password',
                'size'  => '100',               
            ) 
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'user_retype_password',
            'type' => 'Password',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Confirm Password',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(               
                'id' => 'user_retype_password',
                'size'  => '100',               
            ) 
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Register',
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
            ),
        ));


    }
}
```

And the Filter is

```
<?php
namespace User\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
class RegisterStepFirstFilter extends InputFilter
{
    private $dbAdapter;
    public function __construct($dbAdapter) {         
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'user_given_name',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                array('name' => 'HtmlEntities'),
            ),
            'validators' => array(                      
                        array('name' => 'Alpha','options' => array('allowWhiteSpace' => true,),),
                        array('name' => 'StringLength','options' => array('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'min' => 1,'max' => 100,),),
            ),
        )); 

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'user_email',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                array('name' => 'HtmlEntities'),

            ),
            'validators' => array(
                            array('name' => 'EmailAddress'),
                            array('name' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 200,),
                            array('name' => 'Db\RecordExists', 'options' => array('table' => 'y2m_user','field' => 'user_email',  'adapter' => $dbAdapter),),
                ),
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'user_password',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                array('name' => 'HtmlEntities'),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                        array('name' => 'StringLength','options' => array('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'min' => 3,'max' => 60,),
                ),
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'user_retype_password',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                array('name' => 'HtmlEntities'),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                        array('name' => 'StringLength','options' => array('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'min' => 3,'max' => 60,),),
                        array('name' => 'identical','options' => array('token' => 'user_password'),)    

                 ),
        ));



    }
}
```

Comment: don't you want Db\NoRecordExist?

Comment: Nop, nothing works, i try both NoRecordExist and RecordExists ad also, i am getting any error(Error si already enable)

Comment: the movie is just to check email already exist or Not. for coding standard, we want to use validator in Form class. Not in controller

Comment: what exact error is there? cant tell from your response..

Comment: I am already passing adapter from controller. Just wandering why it is not working.Also, it is not throwing any error

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the fact that you are assigning the adapter to the value passed to the constructor, which is destroyed once the constructor terminates. You have to store the adapter in the class. Try the following.  At the top of the  constructor add the line

```
$this->dbAdapter=$dbAdapter;  // this will store the value passed to the constructor as a member of the class.
```

Then use $this->dbAdapter in the filter instead of $dbAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
class TestForm extends Form
{
    protected $adapter;
    public function __construct(AdapterInterface $dbAdapter)
    {
        $this->adapter =$dbAdapter;
                parent::__construct("Test Form");


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use service manager in inputfilter.

config/autoload/global.php

```
return array(
    'service_manager' =>   array(
        'invokables' =>       array(
            'RegisterStepFirstFilter' => 'User\Form\RegisterStepFirstFilter',
        )
    )
)
```

RegisterStepFirstFilter input filter class

```
<?php
namespace User\Form;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareTrait;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

class RegisterStepFirstFilter extends InputFilter implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface, InputFilterAwareInterface
{
    use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait, InputFilterAwareTrait;

    public function getInputFilter() {         
        if (!$this->inputFilter) {
            $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'user_given_name',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    array('name' => 'HtmlEntities'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(                      
                            array('name' => 'Alpha','options' => array('allowWhiteSpace' => true,),),
                            array('name' => 'StringLength','options' => array('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'min' => 1,'max' => 100,),),
                ),
            )); 

            $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'user_email',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    array('name' => 'HtmlEntities'),

                ),
                'validators' => array(
                                array('name' => 'EmailAddress'),
                                array('name' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 200,),
                                array('name' => 'Db\RecordExists', 'options' => array('table' => 'y2m_user','field' => 'user_email',  'adapter' => 
                                    $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')),),
                    ),
                ),
            ));

            $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'user_password',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    array('name' => 'HtmlEntities'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                            array('name' => 'StringLength','options' => array('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'min' => 3,'max' => 60,),
                    ),
                ),
            ));

            $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'user_retype_password',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    array('name' => 'HtmlEntities'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                            array('name' => 'StringLength','options' => array('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'min' => 3,'max' => 60,),),
                            array('name' => 'identical','options' => array('token' => 'user_password'),)    

                     ),
            ));

            $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
        }

        return $this->inputFilter;

    }
}
```

and in your controller

```
$inputFilter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('RegisterStepFirstFilter');
$form->setInputFilter($inputFilter->getInputFilter());
```