# How to check if an email already registered in form

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am writing a Registration code and i am looking for email uniqueness. If user enters a email that is already registered, the form should thrown error.

I have try both NoRecordExists, and RecordExists. None is working here

I have implemented "Db\NoRecordExists", but it is not working. It is not throwing error nor it is checking email in Db.

My controller is like

```
$sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');   
    if ($request->isPost()) {                           
        #Filter the Input
        $form->setInputFilter(new RegisterStepFirstFilter($dbAdapter)); 
        $form->setData($request->getPost()); 
        if (!$form->isValid()) {                                
            #error comes
            $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('Oops an error is occured');            
        }else{                      
            #No error.Proceed with Registration

        }
    }
```

My Registration Filter Class is like

```
namespace User\Form;
    use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
    class RegisterStepFirstFilter extends InputFilter
    {
        private $dbAdapter;
        public function __construct($dbAdapter) {  
            $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'user_email',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                        array('name' => 'HtmlEntities'),

                ),
                    'validators' => array(
                                array('name' => 'EmailAddress'),
                                    array('name' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 200,),
                                    array('name' => 'Db\NoRecordExists', 'options' => array('table' => 'y2m_user','field' => 'user_email',  'adapter' => $dbAdapter),),
                ),
                    ),
            ));




        }

    }}
```

The Registration form works perfectly with all other Validators. But it is not checking Email uniqueness not it is throwing any error(I have already enable the error)

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [zf2 Form class issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833037/zf2-form-class-issue)

Answer (score 1):

The Issue was because of Type.I forgot to put a Comma after in a filter .Strange, zf2 was not given any error

I have update validator

```
'validators' => array(
                            array('name' => 'EmailAddress'),
                            array('name' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 200,),),
                            array('name' => 'Db\NoRecordExists', 'options' => array('table' => 'y2m_user','field' => 'user_email',  'adapter' => $dbAdapter),),

            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong validator, you need to use Db\NoRecordExists.

Comment: @jyoti After a second look i guess something is wrong with the closing ) of the StringLength Validator. Try array('name' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 200,)),

Comment: i have also changed the brackets. Still it is i not showing. Ami i doing wrong or i am doing correct way ?